# Redirect unhandled routes to / in apache 2.4 and CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

A CentOS 7 server hosts a public front end web site at `example.com`, and also hosts a backend API at `home.example.com`.  The `VirtualHost` records below successfully direct requests for `example.com` to the front end while directing requests for the backend to `home.example.com`.  However, requests for arbitrary requests to paths on `example.com` are given `404` errors.

> **What specific changes need to be made to the `VirtualHost` config below so that requests to `example.com/anyPath get` redirected to example.com?**

For example, a request for http://example.com/home that reaches the server should be returned with `example.com`

Here is the `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example_com_requests.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public_html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost home.example.com:80>
    ServerName home.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example_home_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example_home_com_requests.log combined
    ProxyPass / http://public.ip.for.api:1234/ connectiontimeout=5 timeout=30
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect, you can add this to your first `VirtualHost` directive (using the appropriate index file).

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(?!index.html$).+ http://example.com
```

Basically this means you are matching anything doesn't match /index.html exactly and is followed by one or more characters.

You can also use `Rewrite` for a different effect. No matter what is requested Apache will serve up the index file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.* index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, cleanest and — imo — most correct way of achieving this result is:

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    #...
    DirectoryIndex index.html     # This is likely already set globally
    FallbackResource /index.html  # Catchall for any undefined path (from Apache's point of view)
    #...
</VirtualHost>
```

One great advantage of `FallbackResource` over `RedirectMatch` and the *mod_rewrite*-based approach is that it is a set-once-and-forget setting that keeps working when new routes are added, without having to update this configuration. It's also SPA-friendly — unlike redirections — as it preserves the path of the original request. It essentially tells Apache to let the fallback resource handle any request for routes that are undefined from Apache's point-of-view.